# transformation and eigenvalues/eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $S: M_n(R) \to M_n(R)$ by $S(A) = A^T.$ Prove that $S$ has only two distinct eigenvalues and that its eigenvectors span $M_n(R).$

---

I've noticed this:
$$S(A) = A^T.$$
If I apply $S$ again, I get
$$S^2(A) = A,$$
which means $S^2$ is $I.$

Also to find eigenvalue I know I have to find $\lambda$ where $S(A) = \lambda A.$  So $A^T = \lambda A.$

Edit: I found eigenvalues. They are plus 1 and minus 1.

any ideas on the second part of the question?

two eigenvectors must satisfy $A^T = A$ and $A^T = -A$ each. But how do I find them and show that they span $M_n(R)?$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have found that $S^2=\operatorname{id}$ so the polynomial $x^2-1$ with simple roots $\pm 1$ annihilates $S$ and $S\ne\operatorname{id}$ so it's the minimal polynomial hence $S$ is diagonalizable and has two eigenvalues $\pm 1$. Finaly since $S$ is diagoanlizable then we can find a basis formed with its eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

As $S(S(A))=A$, that implies the polynomial $p(x)=x^2-1$ annihilates $S$, and as $p$ has single roots, then $S$ is diagonalizable, and hence its eigenvectors span $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

Its eigenvectors are $E_{ii}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, $E_{ij}+E_{ji}$, $1\le i<j\le n$ and $E_{ij}-E_{ji}$, $1\le i<j\le n$, where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with everywhere zeroes except of $(i,j)$-place where it has an ace. Clearly all these eigenvectors span $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.